# How to write binary to file

Tags: asp.net

I have code that's supposed to read binary values from the database and convert it into a zip file. It only creates a file that's 43kb big and it can't be extracted. What am I missing?

```
com = new SqlCommand("SELECT BinFile FROM tbl_reports WHERE DBKey=411", conString);     
byte[] blob = (byte[])com.ExecuteScalar();
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\" + "test.zip", blob);
```

Comment: Have you written the binary data into a text file and ensured, it is the data you want?

Comment: Yes everything is in the database. I just need to save them as usable files. There are different types, from zip,jpg,xsl etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) , here is example .

```
   using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
   {
       zip.Password = pwd;
       zip.AddFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".xml");
       zip.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".zip");
   }
```

Additionally , I think you need to convert `byte[]` to string and then text file .
You can use [convert.frombase64string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method !

**Edit**

If you want to write `byte[]` to file , use this function ,

```
public bool ByteArrayToFile(string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray)
   {
      try
      {
      System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = 
     new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                              System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
     _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, _ByteArray.Length);
     _FileStream.Close();

  return true;
      }
    catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}",
                    _Exception.ToString());
        }
   return false;
   }
```

And call this function likes

```
com = new SqlCommand("SELECT BinFile FROM tbl_reports WHERE DBKey=411", conString);     
byte[] blob = (byte[])com.ExecuteScalar();
ByteArrayToFile("C:\\test.txt",blob);
```

Comment: I don't want to zip a file I just need to read the file from the DB. Not necessarily a zip, any file types.

Comment: you said that "convert it into a zip file" ! SO , what is it mean ?

Comment: Excuse my 'English'. I just need to read a file from the database and save it.

Comment: Try `File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\" + "test.txt", blob);` instead of `File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\" + "test.zip", blob);` , or you can see my Edit !